# jQuery append text in but in a new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a new line using this this code. I have tried \n and only \ but no solution. What can I do now?

```
function infC(name) {
    jQuery("#dialog").text(information_by_equipment[name][1]).append(information_by_equipment[name][2]);
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.append()` appends HTML. You need to use `<br />`:

```
jQuery("#dialog")
  .text(information_by_equipment[name][1])
  .append("<br />" + information_by_equipment[name][2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog").append((information_by_equipment[name][1] + "<br>" + information_by_equipment[name][2]);
});
```

This should solve your problem. Simply add a `<br>` to enter a new line between your "lines".

Comment: Why the downvote and why did someone marked my answer for deletion?
@Praveen Kumar, why?

Comment: Even my answer has downvote. I asked why the downvote, no one replied. When the mods contacted me, they say it is how StackOverflow works it seems! Hell! :(

Comment: In fact, I voted up all the other answers and question as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, thanks, then I dunno. Btw, I can't upvote for you, I am limited / day.

Comment: Aww.. Thanks so much. :(

Comment: Tomorrow, when it frees :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar, maybe at you, at me is night :)). P.S. It sais I can not do anything since it was answered? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am not allowed to ask questions? :(

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions are not working try this one.

```
jQuery("#dialog")
  .text(information_by_equipment[name][1])
  .append("&#13;&#10;" + information_by_equipment[name][2]);
```

`&#10;` Line Feed and `&#13;` Carriage Return